# Where to store uploaded files in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple (for now) full stack web application with DRF on the backend and React as frontend.

I have various pages, one of them is user's profile. Any user can change their avatar, this is also handled on the backend. I do it by calling the backend API with a path to a file, it gets uploaded to a `media` directory and served from backend, so frontend can access it (apps work separately on 2 different ports). That's how it looks in most tutorials/articles on the internet.

I actually made this feature just now and while I was happy and wanted to commit my changes I noticed that I have an additional change which is the uploaded avatar. Now the problem is, what do I do with that? Obviously, I cannot just add it to my repo, that would be stupid, right? And if I `gitignore` it, then the path like `avatars/foo.jpg` stays in my DB but I won't be able to serve it, because there will be no file.

I wanted to ask what's the general solution (or in DRF) to this problem. First thing that comes to mind is storing the images in a separate database or something like S3.

Or maybe I am mistaken and this is the right way (for example, just for my avatars, setting whole S3 would be an overkill) and the problems with avatars gathering in my repo are just development-time avatars - when the app would be deployed, storing images in local `/media` folder would be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [read these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/) to get an understanding of the systems involved:

> By default, Django stores files locally, using the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings. The examples below assume that you’re using these defaults.
>
> However, Django provides ways to write custom file storage systems that allow you to completely customize where and how Django stores files. The second half of this document describes how these storage systems work.

In short, you create a media directory and define MEDIA_ROOT - this works on a VPS and generally any site hosted on a single server.

On distributed and auto-scaling systems like AWS, you can use [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) to store the media on S3 so all your instances have access to the same files. There's a rather detailed tutorial [available here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-django-rest-framework/).

Comment: Thank you. I read the docs that you provided. However, for now I won't be storing any files other than users' avatars. I think it would be an overkill for me now. So I think you've answered my question, but I wanna ask another side one: is it okay to store those avatars in MEDIA_ROOT even in production?

Comment: On Elastic Beanstalk web/python: no. Every instance would have it's own MEDIA_ROOT, even if it's the same path, it won't be the same machine.